# LINQ loop through a collection and append an increment to matching values

Tags: linq

If I had a collection like :

```
var list = new List<string>()
    {
        "one",
        "one",
        "two",
        "two",
        "three"
    };
```

is it possible to get a result like below using linq?

"one-1", "one-2", "two-1", "two-2", "three"

I am trying to get duplicate values and append consecutive numbers to them to make them unique

|EDIT

I did this in LinqPad, seems right...

```
Dictionary<string,string> names = new Dictionary<string,string>(){

    {"val1","text1"},
    {"val2","text1"},
    {"val3","text2"},
    {"val4","text3"},
    {"val5","text3"}

};

var filteredNames = names.GroupBy (x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select((i, index) => i.Value + index.ToString()));
```

advice welcome!

Comment: Your question is a bit confuse, can you edit it and make it more clear.

Comment: If I can, what part don't you understand?

Comment: Well one confusing thing seems to be your question says you are starting with a list and then you have some sample code that starts with a dictionary...

Comment: No problem, the collection type wasn't really relevant to the problem but I can see how that would be confusing. Think i cracked it anyway thanks for the help

Comment: Also you haven't really stated what you want to do, just given an example of an input dataset and an output dataset. I suspect you are trying to get duplicate values and append consecutive numbers to them to make them unique? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, to be honest that's pretty much what the title says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the list you should do as follows:

```
var filteredNames = list.GroupBy (x => x).SelectMany((i, index) => i.Value + "-" + index.ToString());
```

Starting from the dictionary your solution is right, but if you want as a result a list you should do as follows:

```
var filteredNames = names.GroupBy (x => x.Value).SelectMany((i, index) => i.Value + "-" + index.ToString());
```

Comment: This looks like it won't preserve ordering if that is relevant.

Comment: First one doesn't seems like a  correct solution, there will not be any `i.Value`, also SelectMany would yield `IEnumerable<char>`, instead of `IEnumerable<string>`